# Extension cord or "hub" for USB-C / Thunderbolt 3

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, power, hardware-recommendation, thunderbolt-display

The picture below shows how my desk looks after I got my new Mac Book Pro (2017). The bright adapter is for USB, HDMI, USB-C and Ethernet. The darker adapter is from USB-C to Mini Display Port.

[image: Not quite satisfying situation with cables and adapters]

It's not quite satisfying to have a bunch of cables and adapters right in the middle of the desk. **So I'm looking for a solution so that I can put all the adapters and their connected devices to a hidden spot, and just connect them with one (or two) cables to the laptop.**

Basically, I would need either an **USB-C extension coord or a hub from USB-C to USB-C**. Is there anything available?

Comment: Just a super quick search on Amazon yielded a [USB-C extension cable](http://amzn.to/2zGZTQZ).  Will this not work?

Answer (score 1):

USB-C and Thunderbolt 3 are different protocol in a same physical connector.

For a USB-C hub you can't support both DP(4K 60Hz) and USB 3.0.

A Thunderbolt 3 Hub will be far more expensive than a USB-C Hub. Unless you are ready to pay for it, it might be better to stick on your current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This product worked well for me:

https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock

It is the OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock. It connects via 1 Thunderbolt 3 cable to your MacBook Pro while allowing you to conncect your mini-display port, ethernet and USB cables. It even charges the MacBook Pro (though only at 60W).

You can buy longer Thunderbolt 3 cables for it which will allow you to hide it underneath the desk.

Answer (score 0):

You can't daisy-chain USB-C, so your best bet is get a USB-C extension cable. Also, you'll need 2 of them since 1 does not provide enough bandwidth for your 2 displays.